# How to display entries from current category grouped by another category

Tags: php

I have content entries in a channel called resources.

Resources primary categories are whitepapers and downloads.

Secondarily, the entries are categorized by "brand"

What I want to do is grab the current category id (e.g. downloads) but then display the entries grouped by "brand"

This is my code.

```
{exp:channel:category_heading channel="resources"}
{!--grab main category we're viewing. E.g. we're viewing "downloads" in the "resources" channel--}
<?php $category = '{category_id}'; ?>
{/exp:channel:category_heading}

{!-- loop through the brands --}
{exp:channel:categories category_group="2" show_empty="no"}

    <h2 style="float:left; clear:both; width:100%;">{category_name}</h2>

    {!-- now display entries from this main category (e.g. downloads) that are also categorized under the current brands --}
    {exp:channel:entries category="<?php echo $category; ?> & {category_id}" channel="resources" disable="member_data|pagination|trackbacks"}

        <a href="{pdf}">{title}</a><br>

    {/exp:channel:entries}

{/exp:channel:categories}
```

Where it says $category and category_id, only recognizing the latter. I can accurately print the $category to screen in the loop but the category= filter doesn't recognize it.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a mix of using php on input and output in the same template. Output while setting $category (EE tags run first, then output {category_id} for use in php), and input while echoing $category (PHP runs first and outputs $category as a string for use in an EE tag).

So you'll only be able to set the template for one or the other. You could use something like [Stash](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/stash) to set the variables instead of php, or move the interior channel entries to an embedded template.

UPDATE:

```
{exp:stash:set name="main_category_id" parse_tags="yes" trim="yes"}
    {exp:channel:category_heading channel="resources"}
        {category_id}
    {/exp:channel:category_heading}
{/exp:stash:set}

{exp:channel:categories category_group="2" show_empty="no"}
    <h2 style="float:left; clear:both; width:100%;">{category_name}</h2>

    {exp:channel:entries 
        category="{exp:stash:get name='main_category_id'}&{category_id}" 
        channel="resources" 
        disable="member_data|pagination" 
        status="not closed" 
        dynamic="no" 
        parse="inward"
    }
        <a href="{pdf}">{title}</a><br>
    {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:channel:categories}
```

Comment: nice screen name. I will look into this and update if this resolve it for me.

Comment: OK, Stash doesn't seem to be working either. In category_heading I have `{exp:stash:set name="main_category_id"}{category_id}{/exp:stash:set}` then in channel:categories I can print `{exp:stash:get name="main_category_id"}` to screen but I can't use it in the `category=` filter. My test category is '42'. As a control, if I just put that number in the `category=` filter, it works. I've tried switching PHP processing modes to no avail.

Comment: It sounds like the way you're headed with Stash is the way to go, but the parsing order is a problem. Try adding parse="inward" to your channel entries parameters. I'm updating the answer with an example.

Answer (score 1):

I would construct the filter/entry relationship differently to avoid nesting a channel entries loop inside the channel categories loop.

**SOLUTION REQUIRES:**

```
Pixel & Tonic's Playa add-on (http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/playa/)
Low's Seg2Cat add-on (http://gotolow.com/addons/low-seg2cat/docs)
```

**CHANNELS**

```
• Resources {resources}
• Brands {brands}
```

**RESOURCE CATEGORY GROUP**

```
• Resource Type
   - Downloads {downloads}
   - White Papers {white-papers}
```

**RESOURCE CUSTOM FIELDS**

```
• Resource Asset {resource_asset}
• Resource Brand {resource_brand}
   - Type: Playa
   - Field Label: Brand
   - Field Short Name resource_brand
   - Is this a required field? YES
   - Allow multiple selections? NO
   - Show expired entries? YES|NO
   - Show future entries? YES|NO
   - Channels: Brand
   - Categories: Any
   - Authors: Any
   - Statuses: Open
   - Limit entries to: All
   - Order entries by: Entry Title in Ascending Order
```

**TEMPLATE CODE**

```
http://www.example.com/resources/downloads/

{exp:channel:entries channel="brands" dynamic="no" disable="..."}
    {if {exp:playa:total_parents} > 0}

    <h1>{title}{if segment_2} > {segment_2_category_name}{/if}</h1>

    {exp:playa:parents channel="resources" category="{segment_2_category_id}"}
        <a href="{resource_asset}">{title}</a><br />
    {/exp:playa:parents}

    {/if}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

I have not tested the overhead for this solution, so I do not know how it would compare to the Stash solution above.